# android gradle project refresh fail: The device is not ready

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When i have move my project to my laptop and import it in file/import project, Android studio alert me

> project refresh failed
>
> Error: The device is not ready

[image: error]

Answer (score 3):

Look inside your **gradle** file for lines something like this (this is mine):

```
maven {
    url "D:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository"
}
```

I do not have drive **D:\** with **Android SDK** on my new laptop. That is why I met the error:

```
Gradle sync failed: The device is not ready
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

In the **Android Studio's** log I found the line:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not normalize path for file 'D:\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository'.
```

Hope this post will help other people to handle this error quickly.

Comment: Thank you this put me on the right track to fix a similar error (I had moved project from one machine to another with a different drive letter and signing config couldn't find the keystore).

Answer (score 1):

try this algorythm:

1. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4. Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs
5. Gradle build success
6. Rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

You should connect your android device to computer 
i think you have driver problem .and you should install your device driver 
if you use windows bellows link show you how to install driver

[Manually installing Android ADB USB Driver](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented product flavors in a project then please check implementation and keystore path. In my case it was the reason and i have corrected keystore file path in gradle it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had system environment variables GRADLE_HOME and GRADLE_USER_HOME set to non existings directory, which I had to remove to fix a similar issue.